# Javascript - transform array of javascript objects into a sorted key/value javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have a array of javascript objects of **indefinite** size:

```
var arr = [      
 {
        "Entities": 
          [
            {
              "BeginOffset": 28,
              "EndOffset": 35,
              "Score": 0.9945663213729858,
              "Text": "Tunisie",
              "Type": "LOCATION"
            },
            {
              "BeginOffset": 60,
              "EndOffset": 71,
              "Score": 0.8412493228912354,
              "Text": "Al HuffPost",
              "Type": "PERSON"
            },
            {
              "BeginOffset": 60,
              "EndOffset": 71,
              "Score": 0.9412493228912354,
              "Text": "trump",
              "Type": "PERSON"
            } 
          ],
        "File": "article1.com"
 },
 {
        "Entities": 
          [
            {
              "BeginOffset": 28,
              "EndOffset": 35,
              "Score": 0.9945663213729858,
              "Text": "france",
              "Type": "LOCATION"
            },
            {
              "BeginOffset": 60,
              "EndOffset": 71,
              "Score": 0.7412493228912354,
              "Text": "john locke",
              "Type": "PERSON"
            },
            {
              "BeginOffset": 60,
              "EndOffset": 71,
              "Score": 0.9412493228912354,
              "Text": "sawyer",
              "Type": "PERSON"
            } 
          ],
        "File": "anotherarticle.com"
      },
      {
        //and so on ...
 }
]
```

How to transform it to a key/value Javascript object where each file gives an array of the Persons tied to it while this data and filtering only on type="person" and score > 0.8 and **sorting inside the array the Persons by starting with the highest scores** (when there are more than 1 PERSON for Entities).

For example, the example above should output:

```
var finalObject =    {
  "article1.com": ["trump", "Al HuffPost"],//tunisisa not here because entity is a LOCATION
  "anotherarticle.com": ["sawyer"] //john locke not here because score <0.8
}
```

I tried reducing, mapping and filtering in all ways but always fail.

Comment: JSON is a stand-alone data format. Do not confuse JSON with "a JavaScript object"

Comment: you're right, I mean javascript object. I'll edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below will create the requested output by reducing the input array to an object, filtering out the unwanted entities, reverse sorting based on score, and mapping the remaining entities to their `Text` attributes:

```
const result = arr.reduce((a, {Entities, File}) => {
  a[File] = Entities
              .filter(({Type, Score}) => Type === 'PERSON' && Score > 0.8)
              .sort((a, b) => b.Score - a.Score)
              .map(({Text}) => Text);
  return a;
}, {});
```

---

**Complete snippet:**

```js
const arr = [{
    "Entities": [{
        "BeginOffset": 28,
        "EndOffset": 35,
        "Score": 0.9945663213729858,
        "Text": "Tunisie",
        "Type": "LOCATION"
      },
      {
        "BeginOffset": 60,
        "EndOffset": 71,
        "Score": 0.8412493228912354,
        "Text": "Al HuffPost",
        "Type": "PERSON"
      },
      {
        "BeginOffset": 60,
        "EndOffset": 71,
        "Score": 0.9412493228912354,
        "Text": "trump",
        "Type": "PERSON"
      }
    ],
    "File": "article1.com"
  },
  {
    "Entities": [{
        "BeginOffset": 28,
        "EndOffset": 35,
        "Score": 0.9945663213729858,
        "Text": "france",
        "Type": "LOCATION"
      },
      {
        "BeginOffset": 60,
        "EndOffset": 71,
        "Score": 0.7412493228912354,
        "Text": "john locke",
        "Type": "PERSON"
      },
      {
        "BeginOffset": 60,
        "EndOffset": 71,
        "Score": 0.9412493228912354,
        "Text": "sawyer",
        "Type": "PERSON"
      }
    ],
    "File": "anotherarticle.com"
  }
];

const result = arr.reduce((a, {Entities, File}) => {
  a[File] = Entities
              .filter(({Type, Score}) => Type === 'PERSON' && Score > 0.8)
              .sort((a, b) => b.Score - a.Score)
              .map(({Text}) => Text);
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Noticed that I'd forgotten the sorting. Added.

Comment: sorry to ask but how would you add a filter line to remove duplicates like if var finalObject =    {
  "article1.com": ["trump", "Al HuffPost", "trump"], thenI'd like to remove (only at the end=last process) the second "trump" , is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

For each Object, do the following.

- Get the file name to be used as the key
- Filter the `Entities` according to your requirement (type="person" and score > 0.8)
- Then sort the filtered entities by score
- Then map the sorted entities to their names and generate the names array
- Assign it as the value under the file name key

```js
var arr = [
    {
        "Entities":
            [
                {
                    "BeginOffset": 28,
                    "EndOffset": 35,
                    "Score": 0.9945663213729858,
                    "Text": "Tunisie",
                    "Type": "LOCATION"
                },
                {
                    "BeginOffset": 60,
                    "EndOffset": 71,
                    "Score": 0.8412493228912354,
                    "Text": "Al HuffPost",
                    "Type": "PERSON"
                },
                {
                    "BeginOffset": 60,
                    "EndOffset": 71,
                    "Score": 0.9412493228912354,
                    "Text": "trump",
                    "Type": "PERSON"
                }
            ],
        "File": "article1.com"
    },
    {
        "Entities":
            [
                {
                    "BeginOffset": 28,
                    "EndOffset": 35,
                    "Score": 0.9945663213729858,
                    "Text": "france",
                    "Type": "LOCATION"
                },
                {
                    "BeginOffset": 60,
                    "EndOffset": 71,
                    "Score": 0.7412493228912354,
                    "Text": "john locke",
                    "Type": "PERSON"
                },
                {
                    "BeginOffset": 60,
                    "EndOffset": 71,
                    "Score": 0.9412493228912354,
                    "Text": "sawyer",
                    "Type": "PERSON"
                }
            ],
        "File": "anotherarticle.com"
    }
];
function createObject() {
    var result = {};
    arr.forEach(function (item) {
        var fileName = item['File'];
        result[fileName] = item["Entities"]
            .filter(function (entity) {
                return (entity['Type'] === 'PERSON' && entity['Score'] > 0.8)
            })
            .sort(function (entity1, entity2) {
                return (entity1['Score'] > entity2['Score']) ? -1 : 1;
            })
            .map(function (entity) {
                return entity['Text']
            });
    });
    console.log(result);
}

createObject();
```